# Bootstrap 4 nested rows with same height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

Thought that this requirement was a simple one: The result should be a very basic landing page containing two topics. Each topic has a subtopic. 
On mobile, there should be only one column containing Topic1, Subtopic1, Topic2, Subtopic2 consecutively.
On desktop the topics should appear side by side and the subtopics should be vertically aligned.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<!-- Subtitles are on the same height but the order on mobile is wrong -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Topic 1</h1>
            <p>Four lines of text<br>Line2<br>Line3<br>Line4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Topic 2</h1>
            <p>Two lines of text<br>Line2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Subtopic 1</h2>
            <p>Number of lines<br>do not matter</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Subtopic 2</h2>
            <p>But Subtopic 1 and Subtopic 2 should be<br>vertically aligned while >=md<br>and when <md, Subtopic 1 shold be below Topic 1, not below Topic 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

<hr>

<!-- Display on mobile is correct but subtitles on desktop are not aligned anymore -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Topic 1</h1>
            <p>Four lines of text<br>Line2<br>Line3<br>Line4</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>Subtopic 1</h2>
                    <p>Number of lines<br>do not matter</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Topic 2</h1>
            <p>Two lines of text<br>Line2</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>Subtopic 2</h2>
                    <p>But Subtopic 1 and Subtopic 2 should be<br>vertically aligned while >=sm<br>and when <sm, Subtopic 1 shold be below Topic 1, not below Topic 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I am badly surprised that I have no idea how to solve this. Any hints are deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be using `order` utility classes from Bootstrap and adjusting your markup for all elements to be at the same level:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="order-0 order-md-0 col-md-6">
            <h1>Topic 1</h1>
            <p>Four lines of text<br>Line2<br>Line3<br>Line4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="order-2 order-md-1 col-md-6">
            <h1>Topic 2</h1>
            <p>Two lines of text<br>Line2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="order-1 order-md-2 col-md-6">
            <h2>Subtopic 1</h2>
            <p>Number of lines<br>do not matter</p>
        </div>
        <div class="order-3 order-md-3 col-md-6">
            <h2>Subtopic 2</h2>
            <p>But Subtopic 1 and Subtopic 2 should be<br>vertically aligned while &gt;=md<br>and when &lt;md, Subtopic 1
                    shold be below Topic 1, not below Topic 2</p> </div> </div> <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order).

Another would be to set either a predefined fixed height for your topic columns, or get the highest topic height and set it to all others with JavaScript at page load and window resize.

Comment: How embarrassing - I've read the doc regarding order several times but failed to recognize that the solution is right there... Works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome @Ambix. Wouldn't consider it embarrassing given that the HTML markup also needed a change!